# What should I choose in this situation?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, present-perfect, present-progressive

Why are your hands so dirty ?
Well,I________ in the garden

1-Worked      2-
Have worked    3-
Have been working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“I have worked in the garden” gives no feeling for when you worked there, other than at some time in the past. You may have worked there last year, which does not explain why your hands are dirty now. If the sentence read “I have worked in the garden today” it might explain why your hands are dirty now.

“I have been working in the garden” gives the feeling that you have worked there until recently, which would explain why your hands are dirty.